# rest_framework 3.1.1 with OAuth2Authentication

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

with rest_framework 2.4.3 i could use OAuth2Authentication as it was part of it, but as i can see [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-rest-framework-oauth) , it has been removed from DRF. I used it only for the request' s token verifications with:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.OAuth2Authentication',
),
```

.

What would be the right way to have the same functionality with DRF 3.1.1? The [django-oauth2-provider](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider) seems to be a bit old, and also not working in the expected way (at least i don' t find the *OAuth2Authenticaion* class anywhere.

I also tried installing djangorestframework-oauth(1.0.1), but the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The old `OAuth2Authentication` class was moved out of the core and into [`djangorestframework-oauth`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-oauth). You should just need to change your settings to

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_oauth.authentication.OAuth2Authentication',
),
```

Which will use the same class that was previously available in the core.

---

The recommended OAuth package is [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) which provides their own OAuth authentication class. The authentication settings for that would be

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
)
```

You can read more about it in [the Django REST framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth-toolkit).